# CSS - align a subdiv relative to its parent taking parent padding into account

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8, alignment

I have two imbricated divs, with the subdiv aligned to the top left of ots parent. It could be any other place. How can I force the subdiv to take it's parent padding into account when fixing top:10. If the parent has a 20 top padding, I'd like the subdiv to automaticaly take this into account and place itself at 20+10 from top of the parent.

This question only applies to IE8.
The following example works on IE11 and FF25, but not on IE8.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<style>
DIV.A {
    width:150px;
    border:1px solid black;
    position:relative;
    padding:20px;
}

DIV.B {
    position:absolute;
    top:10;
    left:0;
    padding:inherit;
}
</style>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <DIV class="A"> some text to see what happens
        <DIV class="B">aaaaaaaa</DIV>
    </DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that this works as you want it to in all modern broswers > IE8?  Also, a JsFiddle would be nice...

Comment: Also, I wonder if you could expand on what your actual use-case is. I imagine there's probably a better way to achieve the layout you want

Comment: Having a hard time understanding what you are trying to do... is it something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/NYUhL/1/

Comment: @ZachL:The example works on IE11 FF25, but not on IE8

Comment: @Adrift:no reason, it's just a copy/paste error. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

What your asking is a little strange in regards to normal CSS best practices, because you're saying "when" the `div.a` has `padding-top: 20px`. CSS isn't dynamic like that, unless you're using javascript to adjust the `padding-top` of `div.a`, in which case you could change it with javascript. But, if you want `div.a` and `div.b` to have the same `padding-top`, then you could just declare that in your CSS:

```
div.a, div.b {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: b being inside a, I assume b to match the padding of a, even if sticked at its sides. This is what is done by IE11 / FF25, but not on earlier browers.

Comment: Padding is not something that is inherited, and because you positioned the element `absolute`, it ignores the `padding` of its parent element, and will always be exactly `10px` from `top` and `0px` from `left` inside the parent element, like you defined. If you want the inner elements of `div.a` to be `20px` away from the top border of `div.a`, then setting the `padding-top` of `div.a` will achieve that. But, `div.b` will not follow that because it is `position: absolute`, so you must directly give it `padding-top: 20px` as well. Thus, my answer of `div.a, div.b { padding-top: 20px }`

Comment: That is not correct, in IE11 end FF25, padding of parent is taken into account with the same code (absolute, top, ...).

Comment: It seems like you're citing something that is telling you that this is the case in IE11 and FF25. Could I see this? Testing [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/egZNd/) in all modern browsers (including IE11 and FF25) produces the same result. CSS2 is extremely strict, and it would be cataclysmic if something like basic padding started working differently.

Answer (score 1):

If you omit the `top` property on `.b` it will be positioned as it would normally, meaning that it will respect the padding on `.a`. Use `margin-top: 10px` instead of `top: 10px` on `.b` to add the extra top spacing while at the same time respect the parent's top padding.

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: red;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

I've tested this in IE8 and it works: http://jsbin.com/OnOzOFIX/1

Comment: Of course, you're forcing the margin... But change parent from 10 to 20 will force you to update the code of child

Comment: @Oliver no you won't need to update the code of the child (if I understand your comment correctly). As mentioned in the answer, the child will respect the margin on the parent if `top` is not defined. Which means that the total spacing from the top edge of the parent = parent's top padding + child's top margin.

Comment: But as stated in the question, the problem not only applies to top but also if the div is aligned to bottom